# How to fetch all the elements in a MemoryStore of an existing cache [EHCache]

Tags: ehcache, terracotta, ehcache-bigmemory, ehcache-3, ehcache-2

I'm new to EHCache. I have implemented EHCache for my application. I have configured all the cache configuration's. I found that in my cache's MemoryStore there are certain number of elements existing in it. I would like to fetch them all for further manipulation. Could anyone help me out as to how to access elements in MemoryStore of my existing cache.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet to get you started:

```
cacheKeys = CacheInfo.getCacheKeys();
cacheKeys.forEach((String k) -> {

});
```

Comment: I'm able to get elements in cache.I would like to fetch elements present in MemoryStore of that cache.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API to access elements of a specific store in Ehcache. The whole point of the store system is to improve read performance, in a transparent fashion.

Comment: can u suggest any solution for this problem?